# Database Relationships, I can't understand, MYSQL, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm pretty new on using multiple tables in mysql, so i really don't understand some things..

Here is my php code from my `role.model.php`.

```
public function getRolePerms($role_id) {

    $str = "SELECT t2.perm_desc FROM role_perm as t1
    JOIN permissions as t2 ON t1.perm_id = t2.perm_id
    WHERE t1.role_id = :role_id";

    $sth = $this->db->prepare($str);
    $sth->execute(array(':role_id' => $role_id));

    $data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($data);
}
```

I called it in my `role.php` controller and fed a dummy `$role_id` of 1; `getRolePerms(1);`

I `print_r($data)` so i will know whether it will fetch a data but the output is just

> "array()"

My question is, how does this works?

If i have these tables:

```
roles
permissions
role_perms
```

with `role_id` and `perm_id` columns, referencing the primary key of roles and permissions.

Kinda confused. Can someone really explain to me, in a simple language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check the `role_perms` table whether there is a row with a `role_id` of 1? Because there should be for the query to work.

### how does this work?

First, try understanding the tables and their relationships. I would imagine your tables are somewhat like the following tables.

The **ROLE** table contains roles in your application (e.g. Admin, Guest).

```
Table 1: ROLE
-----------------------------------------------
  role_id        role_description
-----------------------------------------------
     1               Admin
     2               Guest
```

The **PERMISSIONS** table contains permissions in your application.

```
Table 2: PERMISSIONS
-----------------------------------------------
  permission_id        permission_description
-----------------------------------------------
     1                 Can create files
     2                 Can edit files
     3                 Can view files
```

The **ROLE_PERMISSIONS** table contains the permissions of the different roles in your application. Take the data below for instance, it means role 1 (Admin) has permissions 1, 2, and 3 (can create, edit, view files respectively).

```
Table 3: ROLE_PERMISSIONS
-----------------------------------------------
  role_id        permission_id
-----------------------------------------------
     1                1
     1                2
     1                3
     2                3
```

Now, try understanding the query.

```
SELECT t2.permission_description
FROM role_permissions as t1 JOIN permissions as t2
ON t1.permission_id = t2.permission_id
WHERE t1.role_id = 1
```

The first line instructs **what** data should be retrieved. It says to select the values from table `t2` in the column `permission_description`. Therefore, possible results of the query are:

> Can create files
>   Can edit files
>   Can view files

The second & third lines instructs from **where** data should be retrieved. It says to retrieve data from the joint table of `role_permissions` and `permissions` `ON` the condition:

```
t1.permission_id = t2.permission_id
```

**Note:** `AS` *indicates that an alias will be used. Meaning,* `t1` *is just the same as* `role_permissions`.

From the **PERMISSIONS** and **ROLE_PERMISSIONS** tables above, the joint table would look like below.

```
Table 4: Joint ROLE_PERMISSIONS and PERMISSIONS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  role_id    permission_id    permission_id    permission_description
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1             1               1              Can create files
     1             2               2              Can edit files
     1             3               3              Can view files
     2             3               3              Can view files
```

This is the table where data will be retrieved.

So far, the instruction is to retrieve the `permission_description` from the joint table (**Table 4**).

The fourth line adds a constraint to the first instruction to only select `permission_description`s `WHERE` `role_id = 1`. Therefore, the complete instruction is

> retrieve `permission_description`s from the joint table (**Table 4**)
>   where the `role_id` is 1.

Which in plain english means:

> Retrieve the permission description of the role 'Admin'.

Thus the result of the query is:

```
Table 5: PERMISSION_DESCRIPTIONS of Admin
-----------------------------------------------
  permission_description
-----------------------------------------------
     Can create files
     Can edit files
     Can view files
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: you are definitely awesome, you sure spend some of your time for me. it really helps.. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.perm_desc FROM role_perm as t1
JOIN permissions as t2 ON t1.perm_id = t2.perm_id
WHERE t1.role_id = :role_id;
```

this command tells MySQL to join role_perm and permissions by they're shared columns (perm_id), this is correct. but then we're missing the connectivity between the role ids in these 2 tables. the join results in one table containing the columns in the permissions table where the perm_id exists in the role_perm table as well, regardless of whether role_perm.role_id is pointing at the right role_id. the where clause filters only t1. this might result in getting permissions that other roles have as well. to solve this, change the SQL command to

```
SELECT t2.perm_desc FROM role_perm as t1
JOIN permissions as t2 ON t1.perm_id = t2.perm_id AND t1.role_id=t2.role_id
WHERE t1.role_id = :role_id;
```